# Can ScalaCheck/Specs warnings safely be ignored when using SBT with ScalaTest?

Tags: scala, sbt, scalatest, scalacheck

I have a simple `FunSuite`-based ScalaTest:

```
package pdbartlett.hello_sbt                                                                        

import org.scalatest.FunSuite                                                                       

class SanityTest extends FunSuite {                                                                 

  test("a simple test") {                                                                           
    assert(true)                                                                                    
  }                                                                                                 

  test("a very slightly more complicated test - purposely fails") {                                 
    assert(42 === (6 * 9))                                                                          
  }                                                                                                 
}
```

Which I'm running with the following SBT project config:

```
import sbt._                                                                                        

class HelloSbtProject(info: ProjectInfo) extends DefaultProject(info) {                             

  // Dummy action, just to show config working OK.                                                  
  lazy val solveQ = task { println("42"); None }                                                    

  // Managed dependencies                                                                           
  val scalatest = "org.scalatest" % "scalatest" % "1.0" % "test"                                    
}
```

However, when I run`sbt test` I get the following warnings:

```
...
[info] == test-compile ==
[info]   Source analysis: 0 new/modified, 0 indirectly invalidated, 0 removed.
[info] Compiling test sources...
[info] Nothing to compile.
[warn] Could not load superclass 'org.scalacheck.Properties' : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.scalacheck.Properties
[warn] Could not load superclass 'org.specs.Specification' : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.specs.Specification
[warn] Could not load superclass 'org.specs.Specification' : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.specs.Specification
[info]   Post-analysis: 3 classes.
[info] == test-compile ==
...
```

For the moment I'm assuming these are just "noise" (caused by the unified test interface?) and that I can safely ignore them. But it is slightly annoying to some inner OCD part of me (though not so annoying that I'm prepared to add dependencies for the other frameworks).

Is this a correct assumption, or are there subtle errors in my test/config code? If it is safe to ignore, is there any other way to suppress these errors, or do people routinely include all three frameworks so they can pick and choose the best approach for different tests?

TIA,
Paul.

(ADDED: scala v2.7.7 and sbt v0.7.4)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mark Harrah says it is safe to ignore, and was supposed to be fixed before 0.7.4, but he forgot about it.